# How to find jar does not have a given string in linux

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to get list of jar archives which do not have a particular string in their contents.

I used the following command to find jar archives containing files matching string `"hello"`:

```
 find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'hello' && echo %p\n" | sh.
```

I tried the following command to find jar archives containing no files matching string `"hello"`, but it is not working:

```
find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p |!( grep -q 'hello') && echo %p\n" | sh
```

Comment: Can any one tell how to add two conditions for grep like having "hello" string and not having "world" string in the above command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you may just change `&&` to `||` operator:
`find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'hello' || echo %p\n" | sh.`

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the && and || control operators, respectively.  AND and
>   OR lists are executed with left associativity.
>   An AND list has the
>   form
>
> ```
>           command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
>           command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status
>   of the last command executed in the list.

Comment: @jenny Just FYI, there is a V button at the left from the answer, you may click on it if you fully satisfied with the answer and think that is the best answer from all that you may see in your question. You may select only one answer for one question by this button.

Comment: I tried as you said giving me all jars not correct.I want jars having string 'hello' and should not have "helloWorld".I tried some thing like find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'hello' && grep -Lq 'helloWorld' && echo %p\n" | sh.Not working.